# How can I add one record on the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Using this syntax I can add records in the fields but it always add 2 records. For example I input Ana as a name. The output would be 2 Ana. And if ever I delete one record, both records were deleted/ removed from the table. Here is the syntax for adding the record:

```
    <?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="****"; // Mysql username 
$password="****"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="inventory"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="client"; // Table name

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("inventory", $con);


$addclient="INSERT INTO client(account_name, maintenance_type, ma_status, ma_contract_start, ma_contract_end, ma_reference_no) 
VALUES ('". $_POST['account_name'] . "', '". $_POST['maintenance_type'] . "', '". $_POST['ma_status'] . "', '". $_POST['ma_contract_start'] . "', '". $_POST['ma_contract_end'] . "', '". $_POST['ma_reference_no'] . "')";

mysql_query($addclient,$con);

if (!mysql_query($addclient,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: you should also work on closing thos sql injections & checking for empty values/ Notice undefined variables and why are you connecting twice?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: Seems like the first connection merely verifies whether a specific user is admitted to the server and a particular database, while the other connection uses the superuser credentials to *actually* work with the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
mysql_query($addclient,$con);

if (!mysql_query($addclient,$con)) {
...
```

The first call to 'mysql_query' executes the command once.
The second one in the 'if' clause, does the query again.

Try this:

```
...
$result = mysql_query($addclient,$con);

if (!$result) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

comment this line pl

```
mysql_query($addclient,$con);
```